# Why is my radio input can only choose one option in the whole array list of array map?

Tags: reactjs

This is the third time I'm asking because the 2 posts previous don't have any answers, because I'm really really stuck on this problem for a whole few days, so please pardon me, because I have tried a few ways but it keeps not work like what I wanted.

Can someone help me out, I use an array map to list out all of my questions and answers based on question_ID

Here's the json that I use Axios to get it.

```
[
    {
        "question_ID": 13,
        "question_desc": "This is question 1",
        "quiz_ID": 6,
        "answer_ID": 17,
        "answer_desc": "A",
        "answer_result": 1
    },
    {
        "question_ID": 13,
        "question_desc": "This is question 1",
        "quiz_ID": 6,
        "answer_ID": 18,
        "answer_desc": "B",
        "answer_result": 1
    },
    {
        "question_ID": 13,
        "question_desc": "This is question 1",
        "quiz_ID": 6,
        "answer_ID": 19,
        "answer_desc": "C",
        "answer_result": 0
    },
    {
        "question_ID": 14,
        "question_desc": "Question 2",
        "quiz_ID": 6,
        "answer_ID": 20,
        "answer_desc": "A",
        "answer_result": 0
    },
    {
        "question_ID": 14,
        "question_desc": "Question 2",
        "quiz_ID": 6,
        "answer_ID": 21,
        "answer_desc": "B",
        "answer_result": 1
    },
    {
        "question_ID": 15,
        "question_desc": "Question 3",
        "quiz_ID": 6,
        "answer_ID": 22,
        "answer_desc": "A",
        "answer_result": 1
    },
    {
        "question_ID": 15,
        "question_desc": "Question 3",
        "quiz_ID": 6,
        "answer_ID": 23,
        "answer_desc": "B",
        "answer_result": 0
    },
    {
        "question_ID": 16,
        "question_desc": "Question 4",
        "quiz_ID": 6,
        "answer_ID": 24,
        "answer_desc": "A",
        "answer_result": 0
    },
    {
        "question_ID": 16,
        "question_desc": "Question 4",
        "quiz_ID": 6,
        "answer_ID": 25,
        "answer_desc": "B",
        "answer_result": 1
    },
    {
        "question_ID": 17,
        "question_desc": "Question 5",
        "quiz_ID": 6,
        "answer_ID": 26,
        "answer_desc": "Testing Answer",
        "answer_result": 0
    }
]
```

Then I use reduce to group the questions, for example, it'll like Question_ID: 13, Question_ID: 14, each of it'll have a list of answer inside there

[image]

What's displayed in the console is when I'm pressing the next button, it'll go back and forth in the array of the grouped questions that I've just used to reduce to group it.

Then I map that grouped questions to display a radio input, it displays perfectly fine.

But the problem is when I click on the radio, for example Question 1, I choose 1 of 3 answers that I want

[image]

Then I'm pressing next to go to the next index of the grouped array to display a new list of answers
, and I repeat choose the answers that I want

[image]

The problem starts to appear, if I press Previous to change or to look back at the previous answers, it disappears, as I can only choose 1 in my list of array, please help and explain because I don't understand.

The previous answers disappear

[image]

Here are my code:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { Component } from "react";
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";

class QuizForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            step: 0,
            dataQuestion: [],
            question: 1,
            answer: [],
            groupQues: [],
            selectedRadio: null,
        };
    }
    // ------------------

// Get list of questions + answers based on the Topic ID//
    async componentDidMount() {
        await axios
            .get("http://localhost:3000/quiz/" + this.props.quizID)
            .then((res) => {
                this.setState({
                    dataQuestion: res.data,
                });
            })

// Then I group it like the picture from above using reduce//
            .then(() => {
                let grouped = this.state.dataQuestion.reduce((acc, obj) => {
                    const property = obj["question_ID"];
                    acc[property] = acc[property] || [];
                    acc[property].push(obj);
                    return acc;
                }, {});
                this.setState({ groupQues: grouped });
            })
            .then(() => {
                var token = localStorage.token;
                var decoded = jwt_decode(token);
            })
            .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    }
    // -------------------
// The next and previous button to handle switching index in the array //
    handleNext = (answer_ID) => {
        let grouped = this.state.dataQuestion.reduce((acc, obj) => {
            const property = obj["question_ID"];
            acc[property] = acc[property] || [];
            acc[property].push(obj);
            return acc;
        }, {});

        if (this.state.step === Object.keys(grouped).length - 1) {
            return;
        }
        this.setState({ step: this.state.step + 1 });
        this.setState({ question: this.state.question + 1 });

        // this.setState({selectedRadio: null})
    };
    handlePrevious = (answer_ID) => {
        if (this.state.step === 0) {
            return;
        }
        this.setState({ step: this.state.step - 1 });
        this.setState({ question: this.state.question - 1 });
    };
    handleSelect = (answer_ID) => {
        this.setState({ selectedRadio: answer_ID });
    };
    // ---------------------
    render() {
        const { question } = this.state;

        return (
            <>
                <div className="column middle">
                    <div className="game-details-container">
                        <h1>
                            {" "}
                            Question : <span id="question-number"></span>
                            {question}/{Object.keys(this.state.groupQues).length}
                        </h1>
                    </div>
                    <div className="game-quiz-container">
                        {
                            this.state.groupQues[
                                Object.keys(this.state.groupQues)[this.state.step]
                            ]?.[0].question_desc
                        }
                        <div className="game-options-container">
// In here I'm using map to get list out an array of answers based on question_ID
                            {this.state.groupQues[
                                Object.keys(this.state.groupQues)[this.state.step]
                            ]?.map((element, i) => {
                                return (
                                    <div key={i}>
                                        <input
                                            type="radio"
                                            checked={this.state.selectedRadio === element.answer_ID}
                                            onChange={() => this.handleSelect(element.answer_ID)}
                                            id={element.answer_ID}
                                            name={element.question_desc}
                                            value={element.answer_result}
                                        />
                                        <label htmlFor={element.question_desc}>
                                            {element.answer_desc}
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                );
                            })}
                        </div>
                        <div className="next-button-container">
                            <button onClick={() => this.handlePrevious()}>
                                Previous Question
                            </button>
                            <button onClick={() => this.handleNext()}>Next Question</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </>
        );
    }
}
export default QuizForm;
```

Comment: You are not storing all the selected answer_ID. handleSelect() function is just storing the currently selected answer. hence when you go to previous or next question the aswer_ID does not match with the stored answer_ID. here You should use `answer`(array)state property to store the answer_ID's. Your checked condition in input would look like this `checked={this.state.answer[i] === element.answer_ID}`

Please try this once!

Comment: Could please explain more details about this, because I have too many arrays, I don't know exactly which answer array you mentioned, but thanks, I think this is the way. I'll try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to accurately keep track of the user's answers to all questions (even across 'next question' and 'previous question' clicks).

However, in `handleSelect`, you overwrite `this.state.selectedRadio` with the user's current submission (meaning you lose track of what the user previously may have clicked).

A better approach might be to restructure your component's data/state into an array, where each item (in the array) is an object that contains:

- the question data
- the options for that particular question
- the answer selected by the user for that particular question

Each object could look something like:

```
{
    question_ID: number,
    question_desc: string,
    quiz_ID: string,
    answers: [
        {
            answer_ID: number,
            answer_desc: string,
            answer_result: number,
        },
    ],
    answerSubmittedByUser: number, // This is where you keep track of what the user answered for this question. For example, you can store `answer_ID` here.
}
```

Then, you could also have an `index` or `cursor` (as component state) to keep track of which question/object the user is currently on. That way, when the user clicks `Next question` or `Previous question`, you just increment/decrement the `index` (whilst also ensuring the new index does not fall outside of the array's bounds). Similarly, if they select an answer, you know which index (in the array) to update.

Here's an example implementation of `QuizForm`. Although it doesn't use class-based components, it should still give you an idea.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default function QuizForm() {
  const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([]);
  const [questionIndex, setQuestionIndex] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    let hasUnmounted = false;

    async function fetchTransformAndSetQuestionsAsState() {
      const questions = await getDataForQuiz();

      if (hasUnmounted) {
        return;
      }

      const groupedByQuestionId = questions.reduce((acc, obj) => {
        const property = obj['question_ID'];
        acc[property] ?? (acc[property] = []);
        acc[property].push(obj);
        return acc;
      }, {});

      const readiedForState = Object.values(groupedByQuestionId).map(questionData => {
        return {
          question_ID: questionData[0].question_ID,
          question_desc: questionData[0].question_desc,
          quiz_ID: questionData[0].quiz_ID,
          answers: questionData.map(question => {
            return {
              answer_ID: question.answer_ID,
              answer_desc: question.answer_desc,
              answer_result: question.answer_result,
            };
          }),
          answerSubmittedByUser: null,
        };
      });

      setQuestions(readiedForState);
    }

    fetchTransformAndSetQuestionsAsState();

    return () => {
      hasUnmounted = true;
    };
  }, []);

  if (0 === questions.length) {
    return <p>Loading questions... just a moment please.</p>;
  }

  const currentQuestion = questions[questionIndex];
  const [isFirstQuestion, isLastQuestion] = [0 === questionIndex, questions.length - 1 === questionIndex];

  const handlePreviousQuestionClick = () => {
    setQuestionIndex(prev => Math.max(0, prev - 1));
  };

  const handleNextQuestionClick = () => {
    setQuestionIndex(prev => Math.min(questions.length - 1, prev + 1));
  };

  const handleAnswer = (questionId, answerId) => {
    setQuestions(prev => {
      /**
       * It's probably okay to use questionIndex directly. The ternary and IF check below are probably unnecessary.
       * Have written like this just in case we close over a stale `questionIndex`, even though that's probably very unlikely.
       */
      const indexToUpdate = prev[questionIndex].question_ID === questionId ? questionIndex : prev.findIndex(({ question_ID }) => questionId === question_ID);

      if (-1 !== indexToUpdate) {
        return [...prev.slice(0, indexToUpdate), { ...prev[indexToUpdate], answerSubmittedByUser: answerId }, ...prev.slice(indexToUpdate + 1)];
      }

      return prev; // Unlikely that this line will ever run.
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="column middle">
        <div className="game-details-container">
          <h1>
            <span>Question: </span>
            <span id="question-number">{questionIndex + 1}</span>
            <span>{`/${questions.length}`}</span>
          </h1>
        </div>
        <div className="game-quiz-container">
          <p>{currentQuestion.question_desc}</p>
          <div className="game-options-container">
            {currentQuestion.answers.map(answer => {
              return (
                <div key={answer.answer_ID}>
                  <input
                    type="radio"
                    checked={answer.answer_ID === currentQuestion.answerSubmittedByUser}
                    onChange={() => handleAnswer(currentQuestion.question_ID, answer.answer_ID)}
                    id={answer.answer_ID}
                    name={answer.question_desc}
                    value={answer.answer_result}
                  />
                  <label htmlFor={answer.answer_ID}>{answer.answer_desc}</label>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
          <div className="next-button-container">
            <button onClick={handlePreviousQuestionClick} disabled={isFirstQuestion}>
              Previous Question
            </button>
            <button onClick={handleNextQuestionClick} disabled={isLastQuestion}>
              Next Question
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

async function getDataForQuiz() {
  return [
    { question_ID: 13, question_desc: 'This is question 1', quiz_ID: 6, answer_ID: 17, answer_desc: 'A', answer_result: 1 },
    { question_ID: 13, question_desc: 'This is question 1', quiz_ID: 6, answer_ID: 18, answer_desc: 'B', answer_result: 1 },
    { question_ID: 13, question_desc: 'This is question 1', quiz_ID: 6, answer_ID: 19, answer_desc: 'C', answer_result: 0 },
    { question_ID: 14, question_desc: 'Question 2', quiz_ID: 6, answer_ID: 20, answer_desc: 'A', answer_result: 0 },
    { question_ID: 14, question_desc: 'Question 2', quiz_ID: 6, answer_ID: 21, answer_desc: 'B', answer_result: 1 },
    { question_ID: 15, question_desc: 'Question 3', quiz_ID: 6, answer_ID: 22, answer_desc: 'A', answer_result: 1 },
    { question_ID: 15, question_desc: 'Question 3', quiz_ID: 6, answer_ID: 23, answer_desc: 'B', answer_result: 0 },
    { question_ID: 16, question_desc: 'Question 4', quiz_ID: 6, answer_ID: 24, answer_desc: 'A', answer_result: 0 },
    { question_ID: 16, question_desc: 'Question 4', quiz_ID: 6, answer_ID: 25, answer_desc: 'B', answer_result: 1 },
    { question_ID: 17, question_desc: 'Question 5', quiz_ID: 6, answer_ID: 26, answer_desc: 'Testing Answer', answer_result: 0 },
  ];
}
```

---

Side note: You could encapsulate the question fetching and transforming logic into a custom React hook (named something like `useQuiz`), which would make the fetching/transforming logic more testable whilst also making your component leaner (since the actual logic will move from the component to the custom hook).

Comment: Thanks, I don't know that we could restructure our data from the backend to the front end like that, I thought it'll be fixed and can't be changed. The checked and onChange is a little bit tricky for me, I think I need time to digest it into my mind. Thanks for your answer. It helped me a lot!